# UIBezierPath set context

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, uibezierpath, mkoverlay

I'm trying to draw some lines using `UIBezierPath` in an overlay renderer. I get error `CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0` which I suspect is due to the `UIBezierPath` not knowing the context. How do I set the UIBezierPath's context?

My `MKOverlayRenderer` is roughly:

```
override func drawMapRect(mapRect: MKMapRect, zoomScale: MKZoomScale, inContext context: CGContext) {
    let path = UIBezierPath()

    path.moveToPoint(...)
    path.addLineToPoint(...)

    path.lineWidth = 2
    UIColor.blueColor().setStroke()
    path.stroke()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to directly operate on the context, not try to teach the path about the context. So you'd use `CGContextAddPath` and related functions.

Comment: So it's not possible to use `UIBezierPath` with an overlay renderer?

Comment: You can ask it for its `CGPath`, so yes, it is

Comment: Should I use `CGContextStrokePath(context)` or `CGContextDrawPath(context, .Stroke)` to stroke it? Neither seem to work. `CGContextDrawPath(context, .FillStroke)` will render but it fills in the path polygon, which is not what I want. I just want a line where the path is.